# methods that are called when an object is created

Tags: java, object

When creating an object like
`Base b=new Derived();`
sometimes it prints the values in the base class and sometimes it prints the values in the derived class. Depending on the code, it changes. How exactly does this work?

```
class Demo
{
int add(int a,int b)
{
return a+b;}}
class Base extends Demo
{
int add(int a,int b,int c)
{
return a+b+c;
}}
public class HelloWorld 
{
public static void main(String []args){
Demo d=new Base();
System.out.println(d.add(2,3));  
}}
```

when we try to print d.add(2,3,4) it shows error but

```
class Demo
{
int cal(int x)
{
return x+x;
}}
class Base extends Demo
{
int cal(int x)
{
return x+x+x;
}}
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Demo d=new Base();
System.out.println(d.cal(5));
}}
```

In the above code, it prints 15. The creation of the object is the same but the output is different.why is it like that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], it's rather unclear what you are asking

Comment: This wholly depends on the code declared.  Without it, we're not going to be able to offer an answer.

Comment: In the latter case, `Base.cal` overrides `Demo.cal`.  In the other case, it doesn't, because the two methods have a different number of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example, `Demo` class has a method with two params, and the inherited one, `Base`, has a method with three params. Let us see the explanation regarding this.

You have a line in your code like the following:

```java
Demo d = new Base();
```

Since java is a statically typed language, compiler makes differences between the two sides of the assignment, call them *static* and *dynamic types*.
`Demo` is the static type in this case, `Base` is the dynamic. 
During compilation, just those methods are acceptable for the compiler that are specified in the static type. If you override an inherited method in your `Base` type, during the runtime, this method will be called, instead of the one you have in `Demo`. This is *dynamic binding*.

You have two options to get closer:

- cast the static type to the dynamic one.
- override the method from `Demo` and you will see the result of dynamic binding.

As an example:

```java
class Demo {
  int add(int a,int b) {
    return a+b;
  }
}

class Base extends Demo {
  int add(int a, int b) {
    return 0;
  }

  int add(int a,int b,int c) {
    return a+b+c;
  }
}

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String []args) {
    Demo d=new Base();
    // System.out.println(d.add(2, 3, 4)); // compilation error  
    System.out.println(d.add(2,3));  // returns 0, dynamic binding

    System.out.println(((Base)d).add(1, 2, 3)); // compiles and returns 6
  }
}
```